# Approximating open subset of profinite group by union of cosets of ideal

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

I am trying to understand the proof of Theorem 1.3 in this [paper by poonen](https://math.mit.edu/%7Epoonen/papers/bertini.pdf). Poonen refers to Lemma 20 in a [different paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9911267). He claims that the open subset $U_P \subseteq \hat{\mathcal{O}}_P$ can be approximated by a union of cosets of an ideal $I_P$ of finite index in $\hat{\mathcal{O}}_P$ because of the assumption $\mu_P(\partial U_p) = 0$, where $\mu_P$ is the normalized Haar measure. Apparently the details are supposed to be analogous to the proof Lemma 20 named above. However I am obviously lacking some knowledge here as I cannot see how the proof of Lemma 20 is applicable here. I would be very happy about some hints in the right direction.

Comment: [Crossposted at MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/466512/approximating-open-subset-of-profinite-group-by-union-of-cosets-of-ideal).